# Parent element of nested list is bold?

Tags: python, html, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am currently using sphinx to create a complete documentation about the python-project i am working on. The two ouput formats are HTML and Latex/PDF.

Whenever i create a nested list, the parent element is rendered **bold** in both the html page and the PDF.

For example:

```
#. aaaa
#. bbbb
    1. b1
    2. b2
```

Renders:

1. a
2. **bbbb**

   1. b1
   2. b2

This is not the case in all the examples of nested lists that i found online.

**Is there any way to configure Sphinx to render the parent element not bold?**

I am using Sphinx v1.2.3.
Here is my conf.py:

```
    # -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------

autodoc_member_order = "bysource"



# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinxjp.themes.basicstrap',
    'sphinx.ext.pngmath'
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix of source filenames.
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The encoding of source files.
#source_encoding = 'utf-8-sig'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# General information about the project.
project = CENSORED

# The version info for the project you're documenting, acts as replacement for
# |version| and |release|, also used in various other places throughout the
# built documents.
#
# The short X.Y version.
version = '1'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = '1'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#language = None

# There are two options for replacing |today|: either, you set today to some
# non-false value, then it is used:
#today = ''
# Else, today_fmt is used as the format for a strftime call.
#today_fmt = '%B %d, %Y'

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
exclude_patterns = []

# The reST default role (used for this markup: `text`) to use for all
# documents.
#default_role = None

# If true, '()' will be appended to :func: etc. cross-reference text.
#add_function_parentheses = True

# If true, the current module name will be prepended to all description
# unit titles (such as .. function::).
#add_module_names = True

# If true, sectionauthor and moduleauthor directives will be shown in the
# output. They are ignored by default.
#show_authors = False

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = 'sphinx'

# A list of ignored prefixes for module index sorting.
#modindex_common_prefix = []

# If true, keep warnings as "system message" paragraphs in the built documents.
#keep_warnings = False


# -- Options for HTML output ----------------------------------------------


# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'


html_theme = 'basicstrap'
# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.


# Add any paths that contain custom themes here, relative to this directory.

#html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]

html_theme_options = {
    'content_fixed': True,
    'content_width': 6,
    # Disable showing the sidebar. Defaults to 'false'
    #'nosidebar': True,
    # Show header searchbox. Defaults to false. works only "nosidber=True",
    #'header_searchbox': True,
    'header_inverse': False,
    'relbar_inverse': False,
    'inner_theme': True,
    'inner_theme_name': 'bootswatch-cerulean',
}

# The name for this set of Sphinx documents.  If None, it defaults to
# "<project> v<release> documentation".
#html_title = None

# A shorter title for the navigatiotn bar.  Default is the same as html_title.
#html_short_title = None

# The name of an image file (relative to this directory) to place at the top
# of the sidebar.
#html_logo = None

# The name of an image file (within the static path) to use as favicon of the
# docs.  This file should be a Windows icon file (.ico) being 16x16 or 32x32
# pixels large.
#html_favicon = None

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

# Add any extra paths that contain custom files (such as robots.txt or
# .htaccess) here, relative to this directory. These files are copied
# directly to the root of the documentation.
#html_extra_path = []

# If not '', a 'Last updated on:' timestamp is inserted at every page bottom,
# using the given strftime format.
#html_last_updated_fmt = '%b %d, %Y'

# If true, SmartyPants will be used to convert quotes and dashes to
# typographically correct entities.
#html_use_smartypants = True

# Custom sidebar templates, maps document names to template names.
#html_sidebars = {}

# Additional templates that should be rendered to pages, maps page names to
# template names.
#html_additional_pages = {}

# If false, no module index is generated.
#html_domain_indices = True

# If false, no index is generated.
#html_use_index = True

# If true, the index is split into individual pages for each letter.
#html_split_index = False

# If true, links to the reST sources are added to the pages.
#html_show_sourcelink = True

# If true, "Created using Sphinx" is shown in the HTML footer. Default is True.
#html_show_sphinx = True

# If true, "(C) Copyright ..." is shown in the HTML footer. Default is True.
#html_show_copyright = True

# If true, an OpenSearch description file will be output, and all pages will
# contain a <link> tag referring to it.  The value of this option must be the
# base URL from which the finished HTML is served.
#html_use_opensearch = ''

# This is the file name suffix for HTML files (e.g. ".xhtml").
#html_file_suffix = None

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = CENSORED


# -- Options for LaTeX output ---------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
# The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
#'papersize': 'letterpaper',

# The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
#'pointsize': '10pt',

# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
'preamble': '\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}',
#'figure_align': 'h',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
  (CENSORED),
]

# The name of an image file (relative to this directory) to place at the top of
# the title page.
latex_logo = "../../images/other/CENSORED"

# For "manual" documents, if this is true, then toplevel headings are parts,
# not chapters.
#latex_use_parts = False

# If true, show page references after internal links.
latex_show_pagerefs = True

# If true, show URL addresses after external links.
#latex_show_urls = False

# Documents to append as an appendix to all manuals.
#latex_appendices = []

# If false, no module index is generated.
latex_domain_indices = False


# -- Options for manual page output ---------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    CENSORED
]

# If true, show URL addresses after external links.
#man_show_urls = False


# -- Options for Texinfo output -------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
  (CENSORED),
]

# Documents to append as an appendix to all manuals.
#texinfo_appendices = []

# If false, no module index is generated.
#texinfo_domain_indices = True

# How to display URL addresses: 'footnote', 'no', or 'inline'.
#texinfo_show_urls = 'footnote'

# If true, do not generate a @detailmenu in the "Top" node's menu.
#texinfo_no_detailmenu = False


# Example configuration for intersphinx: refer to the Python standard library.
intersphinx_mapping = {'http://docs.python.org/': None}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your reStructuredText mark-up

```
#. aaaa
#. bbbb
    1. b1
    2. b2
```

is not correct. As it stands it gets interpreted as a [definition list](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists).

To get the expected output you need to insert an extra blank line and also to fix the indentation of the secondary list items. Like this:

```
#. aaaa
#. bbbb

   1. b1
   2. b2
```

Comment: Thank you! My intendation was not correct, the child elemnt has to 'line up with the left edge of the text blocks above.'

Comment: @TheBigOlDino Thanks for clarifying the alignment requirement and the need to add an empty space between parents and children. Would've taken me forever to figure that out!